# Shrink Google Play Services library for use with Google Analytics only

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, proguard

Is it possible to remove unnecessary packages from the Google Play Services library so that the library will only contain everything needed for Google Analytics?

I'm asking this because the Google Play Services library is bloated with extra packages, images and resources of which I think are unused by Google Analytics.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Proguard removes unused code from jar files by default also from the Google Play Services library. But proguard cant be used to remove (unused) resources, but I have found that there are other options to further optimize the library.

I was able using method two to shrink an app from `1827 KB` down to `1115 KB`. I tested the app and it works fine and Google Analytics statics are appearing on the online dashboard as expected.

---

#### Method 1: Just include the google-play-services.jar file and ignore R warnings.

The first method is probably the most easy.

**Step 1:** Copy the google-play-services.jar file from the library project to your own project and past it in the libs folder.

**Step 2:** Remove the library reference to the original google-play-services_lib project from your project.

```
Right click on your project -> Properties -> Android -> Select library -> Remove
```

**Step 3:** Add dontwarn flags to your progruard settings file.

```
-dontwarn com.google.**.R
-dontwarn com.google.**.R$*
```

Explanation: The google-play-services-jar contains references to generated Java files (R.java). These files are normally generated when the google-play-services_lib project is being build. Proguard will normally warn you (By exiting with an error) that these files are missing when optimizing the google-play-services.jar file. By adding the dontwarn flags proguard will just ignore the fact that these files are missing and won't exit with an error.

---

#### Method 2: Create an optimized google-play-services(-analytics).jar

Method two is an more optimized version of method one. The difference is that instead of copying the google-play-services.jar file from the library project to your own project you first optimize the library using proguard.

So what you want to do is manually run proguard on just the google-play-services.jar file. For keeping just Google Analytics I used this proguard settings file.

```
-injars google-play-services.jar
-outjars google-play-services-analytics.jar

-libraryjars [add your path to sdk]/sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars [add your path to sdk]/sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar

-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontwarn com.google.**.R
-dontwarn com.google.**.R$*
-dontnote

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.analytics.**, com.google.android.gms.common.**, com.google.android.gms.location.** {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    java.lang.String NULL;
}
```

**Step 1:** Copy the google-play-services.jar file from the library project to the `sdk\tools\proguard\lib` folder.

**Step 2:** Copy your proguard settings file to the `sdk\tools\proguard\lib` folder.

**Step 3:** Run progaurd with your settings file:

On windows: Open command window -> Navigate to the `sdk\tools\proguard\lib` folder -> Run proguard using:

```
java -jar proguard.jar @analytics-settings.txt
```

**Step 4:** Use the first method explained in this post to add the optimized google-play-services-analytics.jar to your project. (Don't forget Step 3 in the first method!)

---

#### Optimization results

```
Before + proguard = 1827 KB
Method 1 = 1206 KB
Method 2 = 1115 KB
```

Comment: Hi @Rolf your answer is fabulous. I have solved the problem the size exceed of dex file also, but the problem on <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> , if I not placed the line on manifest then it encounters error message, if place then shows no resource found. Please help me out.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee hi I am also getting version error please tell me how to solve it.

Comment: You can copy the version.xml file from the library project's /res/values folder to your own project's /res/values folder to solve it. However it worked better for me to copy the whole library project to my workspace and simply exchange the google-play-services.jar there (on an eclipse project that has not yet been moved to Android Studio).

Answer (score 9):

in **android-studio** , you can choose which library like to use :

**UPDATE 13 JUNE , 2017**

u can use this release of play-services :

- June 2017 - version 11.0.0
- May 2017 - verson 10.2.6
- April 2017 - version 10.2.4
- March 2017 - version 10.2.1
- February 2017 - version 10.2
- November 2016 - version 10.0
- October 2016 - version 9.8
- September 2016 - version 9.6
- August 2016 - version 9.4
- June 2016 - version 9.2
- May 2016 - version 9.0
- December 2015 - version 8.4
- November 2015 - version 8.3
- September 2015 - version 8.1
- August 2015 - version 7.8
- May 2015 - version 7.5

Google+

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.0
```

Google Account Login

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0
```

Google Actions, Base Client Library

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.0
```

Google Address API

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.0
```

Google App Indexing

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:11.0.0
```

Google App Invites

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:11.0.0
```

Google Analytics

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.0
```

Google Cast

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:11.0.0
```

Google Cloud Messaging

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.0
```

Google Drive

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.0.0
```

Google Fit

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:11.0.0
```

Google Location, Activity Recognition, and Places

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0
```

Google Maps

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.0
```

Google Mobile Ads

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0
```

Mobile Vision

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.0
```

Google Nearby

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:11.0.0
```

Google Panorama Viewer

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:11.0.0
```

Google Play Game services

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.0.0
```

SafetyNet

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.0.0
```

Google Wallet

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:11.0.0
```

Android Wear

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.0
```

Comment: Linkt to google dev: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 3):

**Update for Google Play Services 6.5+ (only for gradle)**

With the Google Play Services 6.5 release it's now possible to just include a part of the library to your app project. At the moment this only works for gradle based builds.

Normally you would add Play services as a dependency to your gradle file like this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

Since version 6.5 you can specify which exact module you wan't to add. As shown in the example below for the Games and Analytics modules.

```
Google+
com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0

Google Account Login
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0

Google Actions, Base Client Library
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0

Google Address API
com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.4.0

Google App Indexing
com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0

Google App Invites
com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.4.0

Google Analytics
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0

Google Awareness
com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.4.0

Google Cast
com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.4.0
Google Cloud Messaging
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0

Google Drive
com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:9.4.0

Google Fit
com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.4.0

Google Location and Activity Recognition
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0

Google Maps
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0

Google Mobile Ads
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0

Google Places
com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0

Mobile Vision
com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0

Google Nearby
com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:9.4.0

Google Panorama Viewer
com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:9.4.0

Google Play Game services
com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.4.0

SafetyNet
com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:9.4.0

Android Pay
com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:9.4.0

Android Wear
com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.4.0
```

More information and a complete list of all the modules can be found right here: [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup)

Answer (score 2):

Nice Rolf!!

here is my settings file for GCM

```
-injars google-play-services.jar
-outjars google-play-services-gcm.jar

-libraryjars [add your path to sdk]/sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars [add your path to sdk]/sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar
-libraryjars [add your path to sdk]/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/mediarouter/libs/android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar

-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontwarn com.google.**.R
-dontwarn com.google.**.R$*
-dontnote

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.gcm.**, com.google.android.gms.common.**, com.google.android.gms.iid.** {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    java.lang.String NULL;
}
```