# Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 Size Exceed

Tags: android, dalvik

First thing I got same question on several post, but all the post answers cannot give me any solution.
If I unchecked `Android Private Libraries`  then app is running but after the splash screen it's give class not found exceptions.

I have used the following libraries :
[image]

After adding google map for Business SDK, this problem occurs. I know it's exceed the size, but these libraries I cannot remove. Please suggest me to solve this problem.

I am using eclipse.

Comment: Someone have no work, he find out when I place question and give a down arrow. I have no problem with this. Because those person have no knowledge, they doing such kind of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is matched with the answer of this following question, his answer give me final solution.

[Shrink Google Play Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891208/shrink-google-play-services-library-for-use-with-google-analytics-only)

Who give negative vote of my question, please see this link and try to build up yourself like him. :)

Answer (score 1):

I did the following as suggested by an answer found here [StackOverFlow Unable to execute dex...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)
   I had to change my sdkversion from 20 to 21 then added the multidex and Viola

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    ...
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
```

}

After adding the changes approved I began to get another error classnotdeferror, (solution found here: [noclassdeffounderror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298453/android-studio-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-app-navutilsjb))  so I needed to add this code 
and the app worked
added this to the gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

And then add the multidex support application to your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

hope this helps, happy coding!