# Android studio java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

This is my error log acheived with android studio 1.0.2

```
02-03 13:05:23.831    8385-8385/com.******.*******E/AndroidRuntime﹕     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB
        at   android.support.v4.app.NavUtils$NavUtilsImplJB.getParentActivityName(NavUtils    .java:125)
        at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(NavUtils.java:302)
        at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(NavUtils.java:281)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:142)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
        at com..******.*******.****.ActivityWelcome.onCreate(ActivityWelcome.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Configuration

```
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
android SDK TOOLS"24.0.2"
multidex enabled
predexLibraries =false
incremental = true
jumboMode = false
  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3@aar'
    compile project(':ViewPagerIndicator')
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
}
```

How to solve this error?
gradlew clean not helps. Build folders deletion also not working. Android studio shows no errors while compiling.

Comment: Users on some phones report a similar error for my app too. The configuration looks like: [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sanskrit-coders/stardict-dictionary-updater/a5c213592a3759e42ff96f0121839bb58fa1e1ed/app/build.gradle)

Comment: i manually downloaded project from a coworker who have solved this problem, and it started to work. Getting code thru git didn't help. In my case there is another problem with Java JDK different versions - different bugs.

Comment: Alpha, could you confirm or not that the fix i suggested was what your co-worker used?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had this problem and just found the solution - answer is RTFM! Here are the instructions: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Multidexing is a new feature and so requires a support library to be compatible with pre-lollipop devices. You need to add the following to your gradle file dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Also enable multidex output in your gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

And then add the multidex support application to your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Note:** If your app already extends the Application class, you can override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex. For more information, see the [`MultiDexApplication`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html) reference documentation.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Again, see the instruction above for more information...

Hope this helps

Comment: What does multidex support have to do with a "android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB NoClassDefFoundError" error??

Comment: multidex is turned on in Alpha's question. i believe that if you don't set up the manifext as I showed the other Dex's won't be loaded and so the system won't find certain classes.

Comment: Thank godness, this help me!

Answer (score 4):

Was stuck for hours due to this issue but finally got the solution.

Step#1:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Step#2:

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Step#3:

```
public class AppController extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

Following solution worked for me:

1. Add `multiDexEnabled = true` in your `default Config`
2. Add compile `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0` in your dependencies
3. `Application class extend MultiDexApplication` instead of just `Application`

Answer (score 0):

In our case we got this error when we updated "support-v4" lib from 19 to 24 version.

Version 19 contains **NavUtilsJB** class:

[image]

But version 24 does not contain **NavUtilsJB** class:

[image]

Solution for this issue was just to create **NavUtilsJB** class inside our project:

```
package android.support.v4.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;

class NavUtilsJB {
    public static Intent getParentActivityIntent(Activity activity) {
        return activity.getParentActivityIntent();
    }
    public static boolean shouldUpRecreateTask(Activity activity, Intent targetIntent) {
        return activity.shouldUpRecreateTask(targetIntent);
    }
    public static void navigateUpTo(Activity activity, Intent upIntent) {
        activity.navigateUpTo(upIntent);
    }
    public static String getParentActivityName(ActivityInfo info) {
        return info.parentActivityName;
    }
}
```