# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have a next code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
...
private class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(@Tab int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case TAB1:
                    return SearchFragment.newInstance();
                ...
            }
        }
}
...
}
```

#

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment{
...
        public static SearchFragment newInstance() {
            SearchFragment fragment = new SearchFragment ();
            return fragment;
        }
        private class C implements ListView.OnScrollListener{
        ...
        }
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            C c = new C();
        }
...
}
```

When I execute this code in Android 4.3 (<5) I get an error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xx.xx.SearchFragment $C

In Android 5 and 6 all Ok

Logcat output:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xx.xx.SearchFragment$C
    at xx.xx.HomeFavoriteFragment.<init>(SearchFragment.java:170)
    at xx.xx.SearchFragment.newInstance(SearchFragment.java:43)
    at xx.xx.HomeFragment.<init>(HomeFragment.java:344)
    at xx.xx.HomeFragment.newInstance(HomeFragment.java:72) 
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzk(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please post what are you importing in SearchFragment.java. Posting complete logcat would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this error:
add compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

[Android studio java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298453/android-studio-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-app-navutilsjb)

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the support fragment in `SearchFragment.java` like this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

It could be that compiler maybe using `android.app.Fragment` by default.