# Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 with more jar file android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, google-play-services

Hello friends i want to integrate map in my application so i add `google play service jar` in my application but when i add this jar it give me error like

> Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

i attach my screnshots of my applicaiotn

[image]

**my jar list n lib folder**

[image]

**my build path status**
[image]

my project.properties file code

```
target=android-18
android.library.reference.1=..\\appcompat_v7
android.library.reference.2=..\\google-play-services_lib

dex.force.jumbo=true
```

if i remove `google-play-service.jar` than it works fine but if i add it error message comes like `Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536`

any idea how can i solve this ? your suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: its a 65 k method issue. You need to resolve it multi-dex jar

Comment: or you can shrink your google play service .jar as per your requirement

Comment: praveen Sharma : which way? i have no idea about that

Comment: for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891208/shrink-google-play-services-library-for-use-with-google-analytics-only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471772/how-to-shrink-code-65k-method-limit-in-dex

Comment: You should move to Android studio now. using gradle you can use specific google services.

Comment: *Hello friends i want to integrate map in my* ... Hello, did you ever tried to use https://google.com , its pretty easy ... and takes less time then asking the question here, on SO...

Answer (score 1):

This is the 65k issue. Your jar files contains more than 65k methods which the compiler can't handle resolving this. Moving to Android studio is the best option here.Google added multidex support in v0.14.0 of the Android Gradle plugin, so now things are very straight-forward.Find the solution [here](https://medium.com/@mustafa01ali/dexs-64k-limit-is-not-a-problem-anymore-well-almost-2b1faac3508).

Now, if you don't want to move to studio at the moment, you can do one workaround. You have to identify the unused methods in your jar file say,google play service jar file(In fact, most may be unused) and remove that. After removing those methods, create new jar file and replace the old one.
But I recommend you to move to Android Studio as soon as possible, since the Android developers' website is recommending that.