# Remove unused functions from google play services

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am using google play services in my project only for GCM. I got the following error when I updated my google play services library

```
[2015-12-04 14:50:10 - MyGame] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2015-12-04 14:50:14 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
[2015-12-04 14:50:14 - MyGame] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

On googling I found that this error was thrown because my dex file exceeded the limit.I do not want to split my dex file. Can anyone tell me how to remove unused functions. I do not see much suggestion for doing this using eclipse.

I have seen people suggesting to use proguard, but somehow this is not working for me. It might be because I am not all that familier with using proguard.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding just this for [gcm](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0
```

> Note: If the number of method references in your app exceeds the 65K
>   limit, your app may fail to compile. You may be able to mitigate this
>   problem when compiling your app by specifying only the specific Google
>   Play services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them. For
>   information on how to do this, see [Selectively compiling APIs into your executable](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split).

Comment: How are you using google play services in your app? I guess by including com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0 as a dependency in build.gradle.

Comment: I am using eclipse not android studio

Comment: ok let's try this out solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891208/shrink-google-play-services-library-for-use-with-google-analytics-only If it doesn't work will look for other alternatives