# How to compile only the needed Google Play Services' dependencies with Ant

Tags: android, ant, google-play-services

Seems that with newer versions of Google Play you can compile only  [needed modules](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk) with gradle

with something like

```
dependencies {
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.+'
    }
```

If I want to include only  some dependencies (needed to analytics and in app billing services) without gradle using standard `project.properties` file, How could I achieve the same result?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891208/shrink-google-play-services-library-for-use-with-google-analytics-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with what Google provides. [Split dependencies](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) are only supported with Gradle.

Comment: YMMV I guess. Things have changed *a lot* over the last few months particularly - [Instant Run](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AefJXhCxrK8) and sub 10 second pushes to a device has made a huge difference. And there's a [whole community](https://plus.google.com/communities/114791428968349268860) specifically to get help with Gradle and another specifically for [Android Studio](https://plus.google.com/communities/103491657963571270604)

Comment: ok could you tell me what are the needed components that I have to compile for google billing services??
In this list I have found the single component name for everything but Billing.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: In App Billing is totally separate from Google Play services and has a [separate implementation guide](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html)

Comment: So the aidl alone is enough I don't need wallet or some other google play service component?

Comment: Yep! The AIDL is the only required part.